# How to get a Set from a HashMap within a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, set

I am trying to create a Set and Collection from a HashMap that is within another HashMap. The problem is that the `getKey()` method is not applicable.

```
HashMap<HashMap<String, String>, String> list = getList(issues);
Set <String> set1 = list.getKey().keySet();
Collection <String> set2 = list.getKey().values();
```

Comment: could you give me an example or more clarification on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Should that be `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>`? (Or better `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`)

Comment: Unless this is a OCP/OCA question, you would definitely revise your code design.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Why would that structure work better?

Comment: @PalaniSriram I want to get the Set and Collection then convert them into ArrayLists.

Comment: @Danny: You can't really use a HashMap as a key in another HashMap, because HashMaps don't work properly when their keys are mutated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your collection, to get all the keys of each entry, you have to loop over each entry and get the keys, to do that using Java-8+, you can use:

```
Set<String> allKeys = list.entrySet().stream() 
        .flatMap(e -> e.getKey().keySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

To get the value, you can do it like this:

```
List<String> allValues = list.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getKey().values().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Get Keys

```
//Get Keys of childHashMap
Set<String> keys = parent.keySet().stream().
flatMap(child -> child.keySet().stream()).
collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

1.Stream on `keySet` of parent `hashMap` (Iterate on child hashmap)

- `parent.keySet().stream()`

2.Return `keySet` of child hashmap (it's like `{1},{2,3},{4,5}`)

- `child -> child.keySet().stream()`

3.Flat the previous step Set  (it's like convert `{1},{2,3},{4,5}` to `{1,2,3,4,5}`)

- `flatMap(child -> child.keySet().stream()).`

4.Return keys

- `collect(Collectors.toSet());`

---

#### Get Values

```
//Get Values of childHashMap
Collection<String> values = parent.keySet().stream()
.map(HashMap::values)
.flatMap(Collection::stream)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

1.Stream `keySet` of parent `hashMap` (Iterate on child hashmap)

- `parent.keySet().stream()`

2.Return values of the child hashMap (its like : `{1},{2},{3}`)

- `map(HashMap::values)`

3.Use of `flatMap` to flat the previous step (Convert `{1},{2},{3}` to `{1,2,3}`)

- `flatMap(Collection::stream)`

4.Collect values to a List

- `collect(Collectors.toList())`

---

**Sample**

```
  //Parent
  HashMap<HashMap<String, String>, String> parent = new HashMap<>();

        //Child HashMap 1
        HashMap<String, String> childHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        childHashMap.put("a", "b");

        //Child HashMap2
        HashMap<String, String> childHashMap2 = new HashMap<>();
        childHashMap2.put("d", "e");

        //Parent init
        parent.put(childHashMap, "c");
        parent.put(childHashMap2, "f");

        //Get Keys
        Set<String> keys = parent.keySet().stream().flatMap(child -> child.keySet().stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());

        //Get values
        Collection<String> values = parent.keySet().stream().map(HashMap::values).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());

        //Print key and values
        keys.forEach(System.out::println);
        values.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Result** =

keys = `a ,d`

values = `e , b`